# SharePoint : how to automatically deploy a WSP package to a remote SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I'm developing on a machine that is not the MOSS Server. I have Visual Studio and WSP builder installed. WSP builder is awesome because it can automatically create WSP Packages from within the Visual Studio IDE. However it seems the deploy functionality only works on the local dev machine.

Is there an easy way to deploy a WSP package to a remote SharePoint server? I want it to do the following

- Add the solution
- Deploy globally

If the solution already exists, it should first retract the solution, then upgrade it, then redeploy it.

Anything like this exist? Thanks in advance

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support this development scenario. Have you explored Virtual Machines? The only official support for the SharePoint Developement process happens on a server OS and the way many approach this is through VMWare or Hyper-V.

Comment: @Tom Resing, but MS does not prohibit you from making WSP file on your computer and then deploying it on the server.

Comment: @Tom - MS don't support A LOT about SharePoint, and to be honest when it comes to SharePoint, I don't care at all what they support or not. MS also don't support running MOSS on Windows 7, but I've done that. How about installing MOSS on a domain controller - done that too. Or what about running Windows 2008 Server inside virtual PC pre SP1 - done that too, all with no adverse consequences. I tend to take what MS Support with a pinch of salt.

Comment: @JL I don't suggest the approach you take, but if it works for you, I'm happy. Some people enjoy work arounds like this. Personally, I would rather go the easiest route which in this case is to develop on a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a batch script (*.cmd, *.bat) that does everything you need, when you run it on the server.

Then, from your local machine, using [psexec tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), you can call

```
psexec.exe \\servername -u domain\user -p secretpassword "c:\sharepoint_scripts\yourscript.bat"
```

bear in mind that psexec calls the script as if it was running from `c:\windows` on that computer.

Comment: Wouldn't exactly call this an elegant solution. I sincerely hope MOSS 2010 solves this issue, but I guess it will only be widely adopted in 2012.

Comment: No, it's not elegant at all, but its the best you can get in Moss2007, unless you install a Windows Server box for yourself. I really hope it  will get better in MOSS2010, BUT there already are problems with installation on Win7x64

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps using something like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to remotely run stsadm after copying the WSP to the destination server.